# Only counting rows that overlaps

Tags: mysql

Wanting to count rows (* will be COUNT(*)) for equipment booked between two timestamps and it does that but the count also includes rows that returns before pickup.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `equipment` 
WHERE model_id = 1047 
  AND wh_return >= 1678084200 
  AND wh_pickup <= 1678688999
```

the result is this (much simpified), so 2 rows instead of one.

```
+--id--+-model_id-+-wh_pickup--|-wh_return--+
|27194 |   1047   | 1677652200 | 1678170599 |
|27378 |   1047   | 1678170600 | 1678861799 |
```

What would be the best way to do it? I tried different versions of EXISTS and JOIN but either I get 2 as a result or nothing at all...

Expected Output :
I want a know how many model_ids are booked between the given times.
In the case above it should be one; as one is returned before the next is picked up. But if the times overlap it should be the amount that overlaps

**Update based on the comments below**:

souce data:

```
create table if not exists equipment
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    model_id int null,
    wh_pickup int null,
    wh_return int null
)

INSERT INTO equipment (id, model_id, wh_pickup, wh_return) VALUES 
(27121, 1047, 1677825000, 1677997799),
(27137, 1047, 1677997800, 1678084199),
(27194, 1047, 1677652200, 1678170599),
(27378, 1047, 1678170600, 1678861799),
(27388, 1047, 1678602600, 1678861799);
```

sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `equipment` 
WHERE model_id = 1047 
  AND wh_return >= 1678084200 
  AND wh_pickup <= 1678688999
```

will output 3 (id: 27194,27378 & 27388) but should output 2 as id 27194 & 27378 are not booked at the same time (one is returned before the other is picked up). The other rows are outside the timestamp window set and are thereby excluded from the query.

**Update 8.3** Added some of the real data and a few queries. Why do I get different counts?
[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gt9CGVmwaBZaAGedNUDb6/0)

**As the solution is deep in the comments/dbfiddle, this is what I needed:**

```
select MAX(cnt) 
FROM (
   select *,
      (select count(*) 
          from equipment e2 
          where e1.wh_pickup between e2.wh_pickup and e2.wh_return
          and e2.wh_return >= 1678689000 AND e2.wh_pickup <= 1678861799
          and e1.model_id = e2.model_id
          and e2.wh_return_ok = 0
          and e2.state NOT IN ('deleted', 'preprod')) as "cnt"
   from equipment e1
   where e1.wh_return >= 1678689000 AND wh_pickup <= 1678861799
   and e1.wh_return_ok = 0
   and e1.state NOT IN ('deleted', 'preprod')
   and e1.model_id = 1047) x;
```

Comment: Have you tried group by?

Comment: @Jens Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I want a know how many model_ids are booked between the given times, in the case above it should be one as one is returned before the next is picked up. But if the times overlap it should be the amount that overlaps

Comment: Please add some sourcedata for your query. And the expecteed ouput for that data. Also include some "overlaps" in that example data. What do you mean by *"the amount that overlaps"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only count the rows with no overlap:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `equipment` e1
WHERE model_id = 1047 
  AND wh_return >= 1678084200 
  AND wh_pickup <= 1678688999
  and (select count(*) 
       from equipment e2 
       where e1.wh_pickup between e2.wh_pickup and e2.wh_return)=1
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/QFPH96gP)

EDIT:

"the max amount of items (model_id) out at the same time"

I think you do mean:

```sql
select MAX(cnt) 
FROM (
   select *,
      (select count(*) 
          from equipment e2 
          where e1.wh_pickup between e2.wh_pickup and e2.wh_return
          and e1.model_id = e2.model_id) as "cnt"
   from equipment e1
   where e1.wh_return >= 1678084200 AND wh_pickup <= 1678688999
   and e1.model_id = 1047) x
```

Comment: Thanks for the dbfiddle, trying to understand how to change it to count only overlaps (to know how many are booked at the same time)

Comment: That got strange, what I'm trying to say is that I need to know how many are booked at the same time.

Comment: You did notice the last query in the DBFIDDLE?  It shows the count where wh_pickup is between the pickup and return.  If that count equals to 1 there is no overlap.  when the count is >1 there is an overlapping.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how to use it for my need. I'll try to rephrase, I need the max amount of items (model_id) out at the same time (between the timestamps set in the query) if that makes more sense? The count for the data above should be 2. Id: 27194 & 27378 should be counted as one as they are not "out" at the same time and id 27388 is "out" so that is the second one, total is then 2...

Comment: I added a statement that should work, but it's untested.... (because of the lack of data)

Comment: Sorry, copy/pasted too quick.... see last edit.

Comment: Yes, looks good but when I tried it with my 24k+ table I get a count of 490 (should be 1 but I got alot of other model_ids). I added e1.model_id = 1047 to the last line and I changed wh_pickup to e1.wh_pickup was that correct? But it still seems like it does not only count model_id = 1047 or then there is a problem with the time range?

Comment: @nnichols Thx, I must debug a bit more tomorrow because I now get 3 with my real data... It seems that I still get one that ends before the next starts, but I'll have to I have to check again. What about the the last wh_pickup, shouldn't it be e1.wh_pickup too?

Comment: I'm feel so stupid, I works with some time ranges but with others it doesn't. For example when I tried a range where only one item is booked I get 5!! If I try a simple query with the same timerange like in the question with only model_id and wh_pickup and wh_return I get 1 as it should be. How can I get the query to output the rows it counts instead of just the count (so I can see what rows it counts)? With a simplified table (not my real table) I get the correct count, so it has to be something in my "real" data.

Comment: @nnichols Added some of the "real" data to dbfiddle to illustrate my problem (link in question).

Comment: @nnichols Yes it helped a lot, thank you! But what am I missing, the count is 2. The query is between 13.3 to 15.3, id 28476 is between 6.3 and 13.3 (why is it counted?) and id 28378 is from 7.3 to 15.3 and should be counted... The result should be 1. Didn't see the comment about float but I googled and I should probably use decimal(10,2) instead.